# Django migrate tables to new database

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I originally had a django project with a single app and all models were defined in that app. The project, when initiated only used the default database. It has now become an unwieldy app that I'm trying to break down into smaller apps. Doing so, I want to use different databases for the different apps. I've setup new databases and a router in the settings.py file. However, I'm confused about how to migrate existing tables to the new databases.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'db_user_name',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'hostname',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'db2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name2',
        'USER': 'db_user_name2',
        'PASSWORD': 'password2',
        'HOST': 'hostname2',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }    
}
```

I would want an app (e.g. app1) to be moved from default to db2. The router already knows to specify app1 to db2 but running migrations is doing nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run `manage.py migrate` with the `--database=db2` flag?

Comment: When I try that I get the following error: `RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.`

Answer (score 12):

@knbk's answer was ultimately correct, except that the solution involved an additional step.

```
1. python manage.py migrate auth --database=db2
2. python manage.py migrate app1 --database=db2
```

Comment: This resolved the `no such table` error I was getting, but it did not actually move the data from the old database to the new one, it just initialized the new database with the appropriate tables.

Comment: Moving the data from one database to another is not an automatic process. I had to move some big tables and, after the step described in the solution, I just moved the data via an SQL script